# Where is the field mapping for Attribute Transfer tool stored?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-mapping

I can't seem to find any patterns in when the source-destination field mapping is preserved. Is this stored in the database, map document, or elsewhere? I'd like to know so I don't have to create the mapping every time I begin work.

Dialog for reference below.

[image]

Comment: Not an ArcGIS user but my guess would be the ArcMap Document File `.mxd`. Some users in [this topic](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/72661) mentioned saving, closing and reopening the mxd file for the tool to run again successfully.

Comment: That's what I thought, but my user is using the same .mxd every day and saving the doc at the end of the day. Also, I gave her a copy of the .mxd and we had to set the mappings up again on her machine.

Comment: Create a new .mxd, add your layers and see if the settings are saved between edit sessions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The field mapping is persisted (stored) in the mxd. If you transfer the mxd to another machine and repair data sources, the field mapping may not be picked up.

During the repair data process the internal layer id may change which means the layer you now have in the map will be technically different from what was stored in the mxd. The comparison isn't done by layer name for example and attribute transfer isn't robust enough to work out its the same layer. If you dont have to repair data sources after transferring the mxd it 'should just work'.

The help doesn't describe the limitations. I'll check for and make an internal CR (Change request) to look at this issue in ArcMap. It hasn't been ported to Pro yet. I'll also enter a knowledge base article to describe the limitation of transferring an mxd with data repair.